# What are the type T for which following less than(<) operator is legitimate?

Tags: c++, c++11, operator-overloading, c++-concepts

While reading the book "[Notes On Programming](http://www.stepanovpapers.com/notes.pdf%E2%80%8E)" by [Alexander Stepanov](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alexander_Stepanov), I encountered the following problems(Page-07) mentioned by him. Its about the ***less than(<) operator*** for any ***type T***.

- Explain why this is wrong for any class T ?

> ```
> template<typename T>
> bool operator<(const T& x, const T& y) {
>   return true;
> }
> ```

- Explain what are the requirements on T that makes this definition legitimate?

> ```
> template<typename T>
> bool operator<(const T& x, const T& y) {
>   return false;
> }
> ```

I am not able to understand what could be the type of T for which above code works fine. So far I thought(2nd point) that following types(pointers) might legitimate. I know it does not make much sense(not good idea to compare pointer type) and this too depends on the which order object has been created.

```
class test { };
test x;
test y;
// &x = 0x7fffffffe0bd, &y = 0x7fffffffe0be
bool out = &y < &x;
//out = 0;
```

Am I missing something obvious here?. Could someone explain about the both scenario?.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Explain what are the requirements on T that makes this definition legitimate?

```
template<typename T>
bool operator<(const T& x, const T& y) {
  return false;
}
```

Any type whose instances are all considered to be "equal".

```
a < b; // false
b < a; // false
```

The above is perfectly fine for `a == b`. So, for consistency, if `T` had an `operator==`, it should always return `true`.

Comment: Thanks for explanation. It would be really great if you can provide example for this type for which "Any type whose instances are all considered to be "equal"".

Comment: @MantoshKumar `struct AllTheSame{};`. The point is that the "always false" `operator<` can actually make sense, whereas the "always true" one cannot.

Comment: @MantoshKumar A real-world example: The allocators of standard library containers must compare equal if memory allocated by one can be freed by another. This is the case for the default allocator, so all instances of e.g. `std::allocator<foo>` compare equal. (Then again, allocators aren't required to be TotallyOrdered - they typically define `operator ==` and `operator !=`, but not `operator<`.)